# Compare maximum value when all values are NULL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
CREATE TABLE NULLTEST(TransactioNo INT, Code VARCHAR(25));

INSERT INTO NULLTEST VALUES (NULL, 'TEST1');
INSERT INTO NULLTEST VALUES (NULL, 'TEST2');
INSERT INTO NULLTEST VALUES (1,    'TEST2');

SELECT * FROM NULLTEST T
WHERE ISNULL(TransactioNo, 1) = (SELECT MAX(ISNULL(TransactioNo, 1)) FROM NULLTEST N)
```

I have this table structure and sample data along with the query.
I am expecting 2 rows in result set. It should take NULL as maximum if there is no Transaction No present other than NULL for that specific code.
In my case it is either giving all 3 rows on only with max transaction no ignoring the NULL valued rows.

Expected Output:

```
TransactionNo  Code
NULL           TEST1
1              TEST2
```

Comment: Add expected result!

Comment: @PrashantPimpale Added

Answer (score 2):

Your query is like:

```
SELECT * FROM NULLTEST T
WHERE 1=1
```

And This means everything

`ISNULL(TransactioNo, 1)` is always 1 and
`(SELECT MAX(ISNULL(TransactioNo, 1)) FROM NULLTEST N)` is always 1 too

**Edit after seen your expected output: (still no need the where statement)**

```
SELECT TransactioNo ,max(Code ) as Code  
FROM NULLTEST
group by TransactioNo
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use `MAX()` function along with `GROUP BY` clause

Query after `Group by` and `MAX()`:

```
SELECT Code,MAX(TransactioNo) as TransactioNo
FROM NULLTEST
GROUP BY Code
```

Result:

```
---------------------
Code    TransactioNo
---------------------
TEST1     NULL
TEST2      1
---------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Below, Use of aggregate function `MAX`

```
SELECT Code,MAX(TransactioNo) as TransactioNo 
FROM NULLTEST T 
GROUP BY Code
```

Answer (score 0):

Just group by `Code` field and then get maximum value of grouped columns through `MAX` function by `TransactioNo` field:

```
SELECT 
  MAX( test.TransactioNo) TransactionNo
, test.Code
FROM NULLTEST test
GROUP BY test.Code
```

Answer (score 0):

if you not satisfied, you can omit the ids whose value is null, you may see the following snippet:

```
select max(id) from nullest where id is not null;
 -- nullest is the table name..
```